# PHP: Open a new window in new session (Solution Correct?)

Tags: php, serialization, session-variables, session-state, new-window

Since i have not found any significant solution for open a new session for a new window/tab, i have thought for the follow solution that seems to work:

1- created a like singleton Class 'SubSession'

```
<?php

/**
 * Provides a data structure and routines to be able to create and/or
 * activate a subSession
 * @author Roberto CASULA (casual4free@gmail.com)
 */
final class SubSession {
   private static $instance = NULL;

   private $current_active_name = 'MAIN';
   private $SESSIONSTORE = array();

   private $MAIN_SESSION;

   private function currentSessionStore() {
      $active_name = $this->current_active_name;
      $this->SESSIONSTORE[$active_name] = $_SESSION;
   }
   private function mainSessionStore() {
      $active_name = $this->current_active_name;
      if($active_name !== 'MAIN')
         throw new BadMethodCallException(__CLASS__.': the current active subSession is not MAIN');
      $this->MAIN_SESSION = $_SESSION;
   }

   public function exists($name) {
      return array_key_exists($name, $this->SESSIONSTORE);
   }

   public function forkActive($name) {

      if( $this->exists($name) )
         throw new InvalidArgumentException(__CLASS__.": $name yet exists");

      $this->SESSIONSTORE[$name] = $_SESSION;
   }

   public function activate($name) {
      $active_name = $this->current_active_name;

      if($name === $active_name) return 'yet_active';

      if($name == 'MAIN') :
         $this->currentSessionStore();
         $_SESSION = $this->MAIN_SESSION;
         $this->current_active_name = $name;
         return TRUE;

      elseif( $this->exists($name) ) :
         $this->mainSessionStore();
         $_SESSION = $this->SESSIONSTORE[$name];
         $this->current_active_name = $name;
         return TRUE;

      else :
         throw new InvalidArgumentException('The searched name do not exists: '.$name);

      endif;
   }

   public function __get($name) {
      switch ($name) {
         case 'MAIN_SESSION' :
            if($this->current_active_name === 'MAIN')
               return $_SESSION;
         default :
            return $$name;
      }
   }

   private function __construct() {}

   public function __wakeup() {}

   public function __sleep() {
      return array('SESSIONSTORE');
   }

   public function __destruct() {
      $this->activate('MAIN');
      $_SESSION[__CLASS__] = serialize($this);
   }
   /**
    * 
    * @return SubSession
    */
   public static function getInstance() {

      if( self::$instance !== NULL) :
         return self::$instance;

      elseif( isset($_SESSION[__CLASS__]) ) :
         return self::$instance = unserialize($_SESSION[__CLASS__]);

      else :
         return self::$instance = new self();

      endif;      
   }

}
```

2- added the follow line after "session_start();"

```
$__SUB_SESSION = SubSession::getInstance();

if( isset($_GET['sub_session_id']) ) {
   $subSessID = $_GET['sub_session_id'];

   if( !$__SUB_SESSION->exists($subSessID) )
      $__SUB_SESSION->forkActive($subSessID);

   $__SUB_SESSION->activate($subSessID);
}
```

3- created an entry in the .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^@sub_session_id=([^/]+)(.*)$ $2?sub_session_id=$1 [QSA]
```

Now:

1. Since i'am serializing n copies of a `$_SESSION` array (in the `[SubSession->]$SESSIONSTORE` array) and 
   knowing that `$_SESSION` array is serialized and unserialize using a different method,
   There could be some problems when i unserialize them ?
2. Since i dont say in what order php calls the the `__destruct()` methods at the end of the script
    how can I be sure that this class will be the last destroyed? 
   (this could prevent that some other self-serializing¹ will be stored on the 'MAIN' $_SESSION when a subsession² is active.

1: I use the words self-serialing to mean a class which serialize itself somewhere in the $_SESSION array before being destructed
2: I intend a subsession a session with the $_SESSION array copied from a position in the `[SubSession->]$SESSIONSTORE`, created by `$__SUB_SESSION->forkActive($subSessID);` and activated by `$__SUB_SESSION->activate($subSessID);`

Comment: Reason #517 why singletons are useless in PHP.  If you were using a static class rather than farting around with singletons, object lifetime wouldn't even be an issue.  Just saying.

Comment: If the code appears to work, and you have questions about whether what you're doing is a good idea, you might try [codereview.se].